# Trap not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a shell script containing trap, but trap doesn't seems to work as expected below is the code and bash version

> GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

```
set -e
function exit_message(){
  echo -e "\e[31m\nError occurred "
}
function login(){
  false
}
trap exit_message ERR
login
```

Above trap works if I do

```
function login(){
  trap exit_message ERR
  false
}
```

Comment: no discussion about `set -e` is complete without a link to this [table](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions):

> All [...] aspects of the shell execution environment are identical between a function and its caller with these exceptions: the DEBUG and RETURN traps are not inherited unless the function has been given the `trace` attribute using the `declare` builtin or the `-o functrace` option has been enabled with the `set` builtin, (in which case all functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps), and the ERR trap is not inherited unless the `-o errtrace` shell option has been enabled.

Comment: I am still not clear what is workaround

Comment: `set -o errtrace`, as it says.